# Union table where column matches defined varchar

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge 2 tables `x` and `y` having the same columns inside both, But I just want to find just `'EMPTY'` lines on column `name` from both tables and add extra column as `Source` to know from what table the line came from.

The column `name` is varchar(128), I tried to find by `NULL` instead of `'EMPTY'` and did not work, might be better to find `NULL` since I add an extra query just to set `'EMPTY'` where is `NULL`

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT data,name,id,'Friends' as Source FROM droid_friends union all SELECT data,name,id,'Followers' as Source FROM droid_followers WHERE name = 'EMPTY'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the solution 
`SELECT *  FROM ( (SELECT data,name,id,'Friends' as Source FROM droid_friends  WHERE name='EMPTY' )UNION(SELECT data,name,id,'Followers' as Source FROM droid_followers WHERE name='EMPTY' )) as combined`

Answer (score 0):

if you want use NULL your query should be:

```
SELECT data,name,id,'Friends' as Source FROM droid_friends union all SELECT data,name,id,'Followers' as Source FROM droid_followers WHERE name IS NULL
```

Comment: is it giving error? or is name column have NULL values?

Comment: may name column doesn't have null values

Comment: name column is varchar(256), I thought of that too that's why I replaced all empty with text `'EMPTY'` and instead of finding `NULL` I tried finding the text. Still selected everything